# Lookup value in raw JSON data + 'x' amount of characters after that

Tags: json, excel, lookup, vlookup

ive got an excel file and one of the column contains all raw data in JSON format.
Every row has quiet a bit of data and the data i need is 'name' + phonenumber. However text to columns doesnt work as sometimes the phonenumber is in that case in xolumns 'd' and sometimes in column 'j'.

The phone number always starts with:

```
   ,\:'\phone
```

Is there a way i can look for this + the numbers coming after it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure which column contains phone number string, first join your two columns in new column i.e. in **column Z** with `&`:

```
=D2&J2
```

Then extract phone number from that column using `MID()`. For example, phone number length is 10:

```
=MID(Z2,FIND("phone",Z2,1)+5,10)
```